# How does Campaign Measurement Traffic Source Attribution work?

Tags: android, google-analytics, measurement

I am adding Campaign Measurement to my Android app. According the "General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution" section at the link below, the app should get the referrer url when it is opened from a Campaign url. But, the Google Play url generated at bottom of the page only opens Google Play in the web browser, then I can jump to the Google Play app and open my app. But the Main Activity doesn't get any url or data in the intent.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

I want to be able to detect when the app is opened form a Campaign URL.

Am I using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play URL Tool at bottom of the page generates only the URL for the Google Play Store Campaigns. For the General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution (in the official Google page described) you can simply use the normal tool for the Web to generate your links with UTM parameters:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/